# Set cflags and cppflags variables in linux shell and subsequently use subprocess module in python

Tags: python

I am trying to compile source code for a a GUI module called wxpython. What
I intend to do is use subprocess to run a python script that compile the program.

To make this short..Suppose I want to use linux "echo" command to print "hello" by using subprocess as follows:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("CFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security CPPFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security echo hello"),shell=False)
```

I will recieve an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This makes me think that subprocess does **not** set environment variables

Nevertheless, when I use the os module to attempt to echo "hello"

```
os.system("CFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security CPPFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security echo hello")
```

I get my expected results

```
hello
0
```

I am using subprocess to execute most of my linux shell command line...Hence I am trying to avoid using a mixture of os statements and subprocess functions in my python script that can actually do the same thing.

Question:

How can I set the CLFAGS AND CPPFLAGS environmental variables in a shell using python to execute "echo hello" in my linux shell and then use **subprocess** module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a command that can actually set them.

```
env CFLAGS=... CPPFLAGS=... echo ...
```